# why are the object values not displaying on each line?

Tags: powershell

Suppose i have the following pscustomobject:

```
$test = [pscustomobject]@{
    Server = ""
    object2 = ""
}
```

Now suppose I have a loop that iterates and appends values to the pscustomobject properties

```
foreach($server in $Servers)
{
   $test.Server += $server
}
$test
```

this displays

```
Server
-----
server1server2server3
```

instead of displaying them like this:

```
Server
-----
server1
server2
server3
```

how come and how do i fix it?

also, suppose i want to remove object2 after the forloop...is this enough? or do i have to loop through $test because there are multiple Servers?

```
$test.psobject.properties.remove('object2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate through your servers, $test.Server is a string, so you are concatenating continuously onto the string object. If you want it to display like

```
server
-------
server1
server2
server3
```

you need to make an array

```
$serverArray = @()
foreach($server in $servers) {
    $serverArray += [pscustomobject]@{Server = $server; object2 = "" }
}
```

which will output like

```
Server  object2
------  -------
server1
server2
server3
```

Comment: is it not possible to retain $test pscustomobject (acting as a template) outside the loop and then append it somehow to the array? i'd like to preserve it as apscustomobject, i dont want it to be converted to an array

Comment: No, $test will be a reference object so if you did that you would be adding the same object to the array each time and when you change the $test.Server value it will change for them all

Comment: Actually, this works flawlessly, thanks! what about the second question in the post: suppose i want to remove object2 after the forloop...is this enough? or do i have to loop through $serverArray because there are multiple Servers?

$serverArray.psobject.properties.remove('object2')

Comment: Could you just select the property you want? $serverArray = $serverArray | Select Server

Comment: You can use `Select-Object` to remove 'object2' with `$test = $test | Select * -Exclude object2`

Comment: @Rob, i like the Select * -Exclude better to allow for dynamic selection instead of having to specify the objects :) but thanks, im accepting your answer now